# Access a jquery widget from JavaScript

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using a jquery widget similar to the example provided by jQuery UI for comboboxes:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

This combobox decorates a select like this:

```
$('select[name=myselect]').combobox();
```

Now in some other piece of logic, I'd like to change the select, including all of its contents:

```
$('select[name=myselect]').empty();
$('select[name=myselect]').append(
  $('select[name=otherselect]').children().clone());
$('select[name=myselect]').val('new-value');
```

Now how can I get the combobox to re-render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem by extending the aforementioned combobox control. XGreen's first suggestion using

```
$('.selector').live("change", ...)
```

didn't work because the change event is not triggered when modifying a select using `.val()` (at least not in jquery 1.4.4. Upgrading is not possible right now)

Hence, I added this code to the combobox's construction:

```
select.observe_field(1, function() {
  var selected = select.children(":selected");
  var value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

  input.val(value);
});
```

Where `observe_field` is some not soo efficient function found on the web:

```
jQuery.fn.observe_field = function(frequency, callback) {
  return this.each(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var prev = element.val();
    var chk = function() {
      var val = element.val();
      if(prev != val){
        prev = val;
        element.map(callback); // invokes the callback on the element
      }
    };
    chk();
    frequency = frequency * 1000; // translate to milliseconds
    var ti = setInterval(chk, frequency);
    // reset counter after user interaction
    element.bind('keyup', function() {
      ti && clearInterval(ti);
      ti = setInterval(chk, frequency);
    });
  });
};
```

Better solutions are still very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I just checked and the widget seem to have its own change event:

click view source [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) to see the complete example

```
change: function( event, ui ) {
                            if ( !ui.item ) {
                                var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( $(this).val() ) + "$", "i" ),
                                    valid = false;
                                select.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                                    if ( $( this ).text().match( matcher ) ) {
                                        this.selected = valid = true;
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });
                                if ( !valid ) {
                                    // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                    $( this ).val( "" );
                                    select.val( "" );
                                    input.data( "autocomplete" ).term = "";
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Can't you put all that stuff you call under the change function in a separate function and call that function in the change event?

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusion. Maybe this question is not clear enough. The combobox is rerendered, but the selected option (in the `input` variable) stays the same...

Comment: I found a solution to my problem. It's not very beautiful, but it works for now, see my own answer